# Relating the highest powers of 2 in $a$ and $b$ to $a+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove a relationship between the highest powers of 2 dividing some pair of even integers $(a,b)$ and $a+b$. Letting $v_2(n)$ be the exponent of the highest power of 2 dividing $n$, I was wondering if it is true for $a$ and $b$ where $a\not=b$ and $a+b\not=2^c$ if $v_2(a+b)=min(v_2(a), v_2(b))$. A brute force method suggests this is true, however I am not sure and my method could be wrong.

Comment: Consider $a = 1$ and $b = 31$.

Comment: in this case $a$ and $b$ are known to be even where $a\not=b$

Comment: Then try $a = 2$ and $b = 62$.

Comment: i should have mentioned I know that $a+b\not=2^c$, i've just made the edit

Comment: Then try $a = 2$ and $b = 94$.

Comment: can anything else be said about $v_2(a+b)$?

Comment: The collatz tag was because this relates to $v_2((2^a)+(3^a-2^a-1))$ and $v_2(3^a-2^a-1)$ seems to be $2+v_2(a)$ for even $a>4$ and $1$ for odd $a>2$, and since $2^a+3^a-2^a-1=3^a-1$ where $3^a-1$ is the first even number some odd $2^a-1$ will iterate to after $a$ iterations, if this is true it implies any odd $2^{2^a(2b-1)}-1$ will iterate to the odd $\frac{3^{2^a(2b-1)}-1}{2^a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = 2^{v_2(a)}m$ and $b = 2^{v_2(b)}n$. Then $m$ and $n$ are odd. Assuming $v_2(a)\neq v_2(b)$ (for simplicity $v_2(a)>v_2(b)$), we have
$$
a + b = 2^{v_2(a)}m + 2^{v_2(b)}n\\
= 2^{v_2(b)}\left(2^{v_2(a)-v_2(b)}m + n\right)
$$
which is $2^{v_2(b)}$ multiplied by some odd number.

If $v_2(a) = v_2(b)$, then we get, from the same reasoning as above,
$$
a+b = 2^{v_2(a)}(m+n)
$$
where $v_2(m+n)$ is probably impossible to find a nice expression for (I am certainly not going to try), but it is at least $1$, so $v_2(a+b)>\min(v_2(a), v_2(b))$.

Comment: So if I know that $v_2(a)>v_2(b)$ then $v_2(a+b)=v_2(b)$?

Comment: @Daniel, yes. If $a=2^{p+q}m$, $b=2^p n$, where $m,n$ are odd numbers, then $a+b=2^p(2^qm+n)$. Hence $v(a+b)=p=v_2(b)$.